# gitolite behind haproxy

Tags: haproxy, gitolite

is there a way to have a gitolite behind haproxy? I have my repo on a private server behind haproxy, but what is the way to clone/push/etc on this server from the internet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this question a bit confusing? You're asking if it's possible to have gitolite behind haproxy, and then you claim you have gitolite behind haproxy in the next sentence. If it's already setup, all you have to do is type the clone comment. If your setup doesn't work, then this is an entirely different issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can put nearly anything TCP based behind haproxy. You just need to know what ports it uses.